# Private Route Not rendering properly with API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have the following code that is halfway working (see bottom paragraph for full description):

**App.Js:**

```
export default function App() {

const [isLoggedIn, setisLoggedIn] = useState(null);
const logIn = () => {
    setisLoggedIn(true);
};
const logOut = () => {
    setisLoggedIn(false);
};

Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then(async (response) => {
    await setisLoggedIn(response.data.loggedIn);
});


return (
  <section className="App">
      <div className="app">
          <AuthProvider>
              <Routes>
                  <Route path='/admin'
                         element={
                             <ProtectedRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
                                 <AdminPage />
                             </ProtectedRoute>
                         }
                  />
                  <Route path="/" element={<WhoAreYouPage />} />
                  <Route path="/delivery" element={<DeliveryPage/>} />
                  <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
                  <Route path="/register" element={<Login/>} />
                  <Route path="/guest" element={<PotentialLeasePage/>}/>
                  {/*<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPage/>}/>*/}
              </Routes>
          </AuthProvider>
      </div>
  </section>
```

);
}

**privateRoute.js:**

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";
import {useEffect} from "react";
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, children }) => {
    console.log(isLoggedIn)
         if (!isLoggedIn) {
            return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
        }
        return children;
};
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

API Login Endpoints (index.js)

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
    } else {
        res.send({ loggedIn: false });
    }
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    pool.query(
        "SELECT * FROM postgres.public.admin WHERE email = $1;",
        [username],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ err: err });
            }
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                bcrypt.compare(password, result.rows[0].password, (error, response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        req.session.user = result; //successful session and create session
                        res.send(result); //this would be where redirect happens
                    } else {
                        res.send({ message: "Wrong username/password combination!" });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "User doesn't exist: " + username});
            }
        }
    );
});
```

My Login system works fine. I am able to check for proper credentials, create a session, and access that session via the login endpoint anywhere in my application. I did it like this so I am able to at any given point call that API endpoint to retrieve user details including to see if they are a logged-in user for route control.

This all works, however, in App.js when I try to set the state it's not waiting for the API call to complete, resulting in the user always not being logged in. What can I do differently to force the application to wait when that private route is trying to be accessed to wait until I receive the session information to allow the user in? Right now it just gets default false or undefined because it won't wait until the login returns.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try to make use of useEffect hook, instead of directly calling axios.

```html
  React.useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login").then((response) =>  
    console.log('Logged in Status',response.data.loggedIn)
     setisLoggedIn(response.data.loggedIn);
});
  }, []);
```

hope this helps!!